# Add Wistia videos instead of youtube or vimeo videos

Tags: magento2, video, product-video

Is it is possible to add **videos** other than **vimeo** or **youtube** ?

If yes, how is it possible to add **wistia** to integrate in **Magento** and add **videos** in products?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to add custom videos to the product gallery section. You can directly override the `Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml` file to add custom videos.

Override the script as below code:

```
<script>
    require(['jquery'], function ($) {
        $(document).on('gallery:loaded', function () {
            var $fotorama = jQuery('div.gallery-placeholder > div.fotorama');
            var fotorama = $fotorama.data('fotorama');
            $fotorama.on('fotorama:load', function fotorama_onLoad(e, fotorama, extra) {
                if (extra.frame.type === 'iframe') {
                    extra.frame.$stageFrame.html('<iframe align="middle" type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%" src="' + extra.frame.src + '" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen oallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen></iframe>');
                }
            });
            fotorama.push({
                thumb: '<set your thumbnail image path>',
                'src': '<set your video url>',
                type: 'iframe',
                caption: '<set your caption>'
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have refered this code from the following link: https://www.magedelight.com/resources/how-to-add-custom-product-video-in-fotorama-gallery/

It seems the script directly added in template file. For a better coding standard you can add this script as a separate JS file.